# Refresh DIV by command from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I want to have a page that uses a mySQL database for its information, let's just say its a 0 or 1

I want the page to auto refresh a div with the value 0 or 1 from the database at a specific interval.

But I would like anyone who is viewing the page to get the same information at the same time. So I would like the server to be in charge of the interval.

How could I do this?

Comment: websockets or setInterval(recursive setTimeout) with ajax..

Comment: Thinking abstractly, I'd have a single page that queries the database when called, and returns the 0/1 from the database, and possibly defines a 'call me in X seconds' value. Then, when the main web page loads, make a `GET` request to that page, refresh the div with the 0/1 value, and set a javascript interval based on either the 'call me in X seconds' value, or just have it run every few seconds, whichever is more beneficial.

Comment: Send a GET to the server. Server sends a response with the timestamp that the client should make the next request. Don't forget to factor in latency offsets and differences in the client time/server time. You can do this by sending the client time to the server so that it can apply it as an offset. Or, you could use something like socket.io/WebSockets to setup a publish/subscribe system.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this months later without leaving a comment as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1) [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) is the latest of the technologies. If you really want *near realtime* update of the page and have an Infrastructure providing the possibilities, that is the way to go

2) [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or `long polling` would be a second alternative

3) The most primitive - but working - startingpoint would be to constantly poll your server. [Stackoverflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223829/jquery-recursive-ajax-poll-using-settimeout-to-control-the-poll-interval)

Answer (score -2):

You can use a JavaScript timer that will check server for any updates and return updated values to the client using Ajax. You can use `setTimeout()` function as given here:[Jquery/Ajax call with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542863/jquery-ajax-call-with-timer)

A sample you can try
`(function worker() {
  $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    // Now that we've completed the request schedule the next one.
    $('.result').html(data);
    setTimeout(worker, 5000);
  });
})();`