# jQuery recursive ajax poll using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-polling

This question is related to this: [jQuery recursive ajax poll using setTimeout to control the poll interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223829/jquery-recursive-ajax-poll-using-settimeout-to-control-the-poll-interval), but slightly different and I cannot figure out why.

```
function _poll(n) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/check_status",
    type: "POST",
    data: {state: 0},
    success: function(xhr) {
       var data = $.parseJSON(xhr)
       if (data.status == 0) {
         poll(n)
       }
    }
  });
}

function poll(n) {
  setTimeout(_poll(n), 5000);
}
```

Like the other question, the request is also sent out crazy.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Note, I have to use different names "poll" and "_poll" for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is on this line:

```
setTimeout(_poll(n), 5000);
```

You're invoking the function and passing its return value, you have to pass it in as an argument. E.g. think about how this code would execute:

```
setTimeout(Math.Sum(2, 7), 5000);
```

It would return 9 as the first variable, not the function itself.

The easiest way to fix this is to use this format instead, which defines an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ _poll(n) }, 5000);
```